# What does “not one of them“ mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, negation

Does "not one of them" mean “more than one of them” or  “none of them”?

Example:

> **Not one of them** thought it necessary to avoid dogmatic statements about unicorns because he had never seen one of them.

Comment: One = the number 1. Not one = the number zero = none.

Comment: @YosefBaskin, not maths (because 'Not one' doesn't just '= the number zero', it also equals two, three, four etc), but english:  **n**ot **one** == none

Comment: @YosefBaskin : careful, because this alone is not sufficient. You can say *"I received not one, but two gifts"*. It's important that it's followed by *"... of them"*

Comment: "Not one of them" = "none of them".  However, "not one of them" is *stronger* than "none of them".

Comment: The phrase is used a lot in the bible: "And the waters covered their enemies: there was not one of them left."

Answer (score 22):

Strictly mathematically, if you only had "not one", it could mean zero, or could mean a hundred, or any other number besides 1.

However, this idiom ("not one **of them**") is a stronger version of "none of them". It means "none of them", but with more [emotion](https://youtu.be/rpBoAnIIL1M?t=20). Like in an exasperation, a hope that at least one of them would do something, but then realizing that **not even one of them** was willing to do it.

This idiom is basically a shortened form of "not even one of them".

Comment: Only your first paragraph is right.  'Not one' *isn't* an idiom on its own (though it is part of [other idioms](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22not+one%22+idiom) eg:'not one red cent', 'if it's not one thing, it's another').  There's no *strength* to 'not one' or weakness to 'none'.   Basically, they are [interchangeable](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/146047/89) except where they are not.  The *emotion* in your example (I'd just call it emphasis) disappears without the word 'even' in there.  "Not one of them was willing ..." isn't stronger than "None of them was willing ...". ->

Comment: The last para is just wrong. "Not one' isn't 'basically a shortened version of 'not even one"'. The two phrases are different simply because 'even' adds  emphasis. See the links in my answer, plus [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/none), [Oxford](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/none_1), [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/none), [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/none).  They all define none as not one (Collins actually defines none as not even one).  None (not one) of them mention strength.

Comment: @mcalex, sorry but I have to disagree. Even if the technical literal definition is that "not one" and "none" are equivalent, when I hear "not one of them" in place of "none of them", the former does have an added emphasis. As a native speaker I hear it, and it would be wrong to say to a non-native speaker the two phrases are always identical and interchangeable.

Answer (score 14):

The [etymology](https://www.etymonline.com/word/None) (in fact, even the [definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/none)) of *none* is literally 'not one', so technically the quote is just using the long version of 'None'.  Read like that it becomes:

> None of them thought it necessary to avoid ...

It is a potential confusion point as strictly speaking, 'not one' could logically refer to any other digit in the base 10 system and while I can't think of an instance off hand, I am sure the term has been used - either for effect, or as a punchline/payoff - in its literal sense.

Comment: I can't think of an exact usage of "not one of them" meaning more than one (other than a bad pun), but similar phrases exist where this ambiguity does apply, e.g. "An explanation? I can't find one. Can you?" vs "An explanation? I can't find one, but _two_ possible explanations for why this happened!".

Comment: +1 for the etymology

Comment: You don't need base 10 to have a well-defined notion of "one"... "one" means the same thing in any base.

Comment: @Flater, I made up this example: `And how many of his last three press statements were lies? Not one of them, not two, all three of them were simply not true! He really _is_ a notorious liar.` Here, "not one of them" does not prepare the punchline (payoff) of a joke, it's added for emphasis. [Disclaimer: I'm not a native speaker, so the style may be off in my example.]

Comment: I could easily imagine saying "not *one* of them", with appropriate emphasis, in response to a question of the form "did one of them [X]?" - meaning that more than one of them did, in fact, [X]. But the unusual emphasis is necessary to convey that the meaning is different. However, a statement like "not one, not two, but three of them ..." would be common idiomatic English used to emphasise a number that might otherwise seem small.

Comment: @LeeMosher  'one' isn't the problem, 'not' is.  In say, a binary system, 'not one' unambiguously refers to zero whereas it doesn't in base 10

Comment: I guess what I was trying (not very clearly) to say is that in actual usage, the ambiguity of the phrase "not one" is using it for other larger numbers, not just with other digits, similar to the suggestion of @Carcer. For example, a possible line from a zombie movie: "Not one, hundreds!"

Comment: @LeeMosher Yes, but my point is with a binary system you have an inherent concept of not one, but the other. Yosef's comment to OP shows this line of thought.  Because we have a bunch of digits in the base 10 system the thought process includes 'one of a bunch of others (which easily incorporates multi-digit numbers)' as well as 'one or the other'   I just reckon if we counted in binary this question wouldn't exist, because even though 'not one' *coooould* mean '... but one hundred', or '... but one thousand', it would be far more plausible - almost exclusively, even - to mean '... but zero'.

Comment: You can think of it in the following way: If someone asks "How many apples do we have left?", and you have none, you might reply "Not one!"  If you have 2 or more apples, then you also have 1.  Anything that is physically countable, if you have any number of them, you also have every non-negative number less than that.  (Negative numbers would be meaningless in this context.)  Thus the only time you can truthfully say "not one" is if you have none.

Comment: It would be idiomatic to say "Not *just* one" to indicate multiples.

Answer (score 10):

"Not one of them" means "none of them." "Not one of them" emphasizes that no single person among them thought it was necessary.

Answer (score 4):

"Not one of them" implies none of them thought it necessary.

Answer (score -1):

"Not one of them" is just a confusing way of saying "not **any** of them"

Comment: Except that "not any of them" is not idiomatic English, whereas "Not one of them" or "None of them" is.